# BIND9 wildcard and unqualified name

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, wildcard

When an unqualified name (a name without a terminating dot) is encountered in a zone file, BIND9 appends the origin value (`$ORIGIN` directive) to it.

Example:

```
ns.domain.tld.    IN    A    SERVER_IP
```

The above line is equivalent to:

```
$ORIGIN    domain.tld.
ns                IN    A    SERVER_IP
```

I was wondering if it works for wildwards as well.
For example, is this:

```
*.domain.tld.    IN    A    SERVER_IP
```

equivalent to

```
$ORIGIN    domain.tld.
*                IN    A    SERVER_IP
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't make any difference in this respect that the owner name is a wildcard.

```
*.example.com.    IN    A    192.0.2.7
```

and

```
$ORIGIN    example.com.
*                IN     A    192.0.2.7
```

are equivalent.